# Storing issue for special character in table in rhomobile

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

using CGI escape i able to save some special character in DB. But I faced a critical issue related to column size.
In one case data size in one column is 12 character. when  user inserted 11 spacial character in a view form. then if I escape those spacial character and try to save those whole string in DB, then it is giving a error and that is because of the length if character after escaping 11 spacial character is more than table'c column size(i.e 12 char).

How to solve this type of error ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for storing in Database with RhoMobile.

[Using the Local Database with Rhom](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom)